# Accessing member of an unnamed namespace when the outer namespace has a member with the same name

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here is the test code

```
extern "C" {int printf(const char *, ...);}
namespace PS
{
   int x = 10; // A
   // some more code

   namespace {    
      int x = 20; // B
   }
   // more code
}

int main()
{
   printf("%d", PS::x); // prints 10
}
```

Is there any way to access inner(unnamed) namespace's `x` inside `main`?

I dont want to change code inside `PS`. Apologies if the code looks highly impractical.

P.S: I tend to use the name `x` quite often.

Comment: What about… just avoiding this?

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the unnamed namespace? I mean, can you add code to unnamed namespace?

Comment: You could write an accessor function, within the nameless-space

Comment: Alright. But I can add code the way I did in my solution?

Comment: you really ought to work on your naming convention

Answer (score 5):

No. The only way to specify a namespace is by name, and the inner namespace has no name.

Assuming you can't rename either variable, you could reopen the inner namespace and add a differently-named accessor function or reference:

```
namespace PS {
    namespace {
        int & inner_x = x;
    }
}

printf("%d", PS::inner_x);
```

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know you could reopen the same unnamed namespace, I thought they were unique. +1

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add this code:

```
namespace PS
{
   namespace
   {
      namespace access
      {
          int &xref = x;
      }
   }
}
```

and then you can access what you want:

```
std::cout << PS::access::xref << std::endl; //prints 20!
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/peqEs